# How can I replace certain characters in a line, based on existence of data...?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I have several files that have formatted data.  Depending on the file, the format will be different. 
Based on this, I use variables to define the positions, so I only have to change the variable in my scripts.

The script I'm working on now, I want to Look for the 'existence' of data in a position of the file.  If data exists (non-blank), then I need to split that data and move half of that data to another section, and move the second half of the data into another position.
Below are the positions and some notional data to describe what I'm trying to do.

Field_1_Position=26

Field_2_Position=41

Field_3_Position=56

Field_Length=10

CURRENT DATA:

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|    
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXX1122334455XXXXX----------XXXXXAABBCCDDEEZZZZZ
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXX1122334455XXXXXZZYYXXWWVVXXXXXAABBCCDDEEZZZZZ
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXX1122334455XXXXX----------XXXXXAABBCCDDEEZZZZZ
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXX1122334455XXXXX----------XXXXXAABBCCDDEEZZZZZ
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXX1122334455XXXXXMMNNOOPPQQXXXXXAABBCCDDEEZZZZZ
```

My problem is with (What I'm calling" Field 2.  Most of the time these (10) characters are blank (Not 'dashes' as represented here!).  However, if data does exist, I need to take the first five characters and put them into the first five characters of Field 1, I then need to take the second five characters of field2 and put them into the first five characters of field 3.  Fields where these 10 characters are empty need to remain as is (Though I would like to keep them as fields so I can insert escape codes to color the columns delineate the fields defined by the variables.

DESIRED:

```
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|    
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXX1122334455XXXXX----------XXXXXAABBCCDDEEZZZZZ
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXXZZYYX34455XXXXXZZYYXXWWVVXXXXXXWWVVCDDEEZZZZZ
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXX1122334455XXXXX----------XXXXXAABBCCDDEEZZZZZ
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXX1122334455XXXXX----------XXXXXAABBCCDDEEZZZZZ
201401010001AABBCCDDXXXXXMMNNO34455XXXXXMMNNOOPPQQXXXXXOPPQQCDDEEZZZZZ
```

Appreciate any thoughts on this!

--Edited to show actual position numbers for sample data.
KSL.

Comment: What does this have to do with regex, Linux, awk, or sed? I don't see any code or anything Linux-specific here.

Comment: If you post the real input data and the real field positions, then I will post a solution.

Comment: Field 2 should remain unchanged.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen, Thanks for looking, but I can't post the actual data due to the nature of the data.  The field positions would be (in my case) defined by variables. (in this case Field_1_Position, Field_2_Position, Field_3_Position); note these are my actual field positions...but I assumed you wouldn't want me to put lines 300+ characters wide.

Comment: Good points (well, except the lazy part :) I've edited original to reflect actual position numbers of the sample data.

Comment: @AndrewArnold, true but since I'm doing this in RHEL, I don't want the solution to be outside of RHEL; I see that I should specify RHEL in my question rather than in the tags (so much to learn...)

Comment: Line 2 of your desired output is wrong. XXXXXZZYYW should be XXXXXZZYYX, but I can't make 1 character edits to questions.

Comment: If the question was consistent with itself and better expressed, I am pretty certain the solution is easy using `gawk`'s FIELDWIDTHS="26 15 15..." which would parse it all up for you without any ugly `substr()`s.

Comment: ...continued from my previous comment. See here http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_44.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat current.txt \
| awk '{
 if(substr($0,41,10)=="----------") {print $0} else {
  printf substr($0,1,25)substr($0,41,5)substr($0,31,5)substr($0,36,20)substr($0,46,5)substr($0,61,99)"\n"}}'
```

You can pass the field positions as variables to awk with:

```
awk -v field1=26 -v field2=41 -v field3=56
```

Comment: Thanks Tommy, This looks just like what I wanted; but wasn't sure how to split the 5 characters, or check for the blank spaces.  Will check it out first thing in the morning.  KSL.

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I needed, other than the variables!  I've created my variables in my csh script, so I'm referencing them as

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I needed, other than the variables!  I've created my variables in my csh script, so I'm referencing them as substr($0,"'Field_1_pos'",5), etc.  I assume using -v field1=xx would be referenced the same way?  substr($0,"'field1'",10) etc?

Answer (score 1):

I find your question very hard to understand, but want to show you how to split the fields easily with `gawk`'s FIELDWIDTHS variable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="7 13 5 10 10 10 10"}  {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

Output:

```
2014010 10001AABBCCDD XXXXX 1122334455
2014010 10001AABBCCDD XXXXX 1122334455
2014010 10001AABBCCDD XXXXX 1122334455
2014010 10001AABBCCDD XXXXX 1122334455
2014010 10001AABBCCDD XXXXX 1122334455
```

Of course, you could pass a value for FIELDWIDTHS into `awk` via a variable too, if you want.

Comment: Thanks Mark, This actually looks awesome!  Currently I'm calculating all the field starting points and field lengths in shell variables and passing to awk.  This looks much simpler!  Will definitely be giving this a try!  Thanks!